# Querying for nodes with multiple relationships of the same type

Tags: neo4j

I'm just starting to learn about Neo4J and I thought up a question I haven't seen an answer to in the reading I've been doing so far.

I believe it's possible for a Node to be connected to another Node with the same relationship multiple times.

Is it possible to return only the nodes where the number of Relationship edges meets some criteria?

Example:

Friend is a node.
Poked is a relationship.

- Friend A has poked Friend B
- Friend A has poked Friend B
- Friend B has poked Friend C

How would I query this so only Friend A is selected because it has poked the same friend more than once?

If it matters; I'll be using Java and Spring's Data Graph module.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to use Cypher. Who wouldn't, right?

Cypher doesn't have the SQL equivalent of HAVING, so you will have to do a little bit in your host language. The query would look something like this:

```
START friendA=node:person(name="Michael") 
MATCH friendA-[:POKED]->friendB 
RETURN friendB, count(*)
```

Now, with the resulting iterable of maps, exclude from the final result all maps where count(*) is different from what you want it to be.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Doesn't make sense sorry. What is count(*)? I cannot see how that will let me only return Friend A. From what I know Neo4J will return a Set, so Friend B will be returned once, I don't see where I can put a 'has poked at least twice' in the query? I'll be playing around using Spring's Data Graph module.

Comment: SDN will not necessarily return a set. It depends where you execute this query? Is it part of a repository? Or an annotated repo-method or field? You could have it return either an Collection<Map<String,Object>> for the results where each map represents one row, you would have to filter on the count(*) column on your own. If you order your query by count(*) desc, you only have to take the top-n results that have more than 1 friend in the count(*) field.